# crack of the door

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

Through the the open window and the **crack of the door**, the wind came in, and rustled the book pages.

the preposition is "**of**" as opposed to "**around**".

What does "crack of the door" refer to?

1) the door was open and there is a crack

like this:    [image]

2) it refers to that kind of crack when the door is closed.

like this:  [image]

3) The door is broken, and crack refers to chinks

like this: [image]

All the pictures came from Google search.

Comment: @Josh61, this is a different question, because the preposition is "of" not "around", and the answer in that question still cannot solve my problem.

Comment: Unless the context makes it clear that the door (a) has cracks in it or around it, or (b) is partly open, your example "crack of the door" is simply imprecise. Usually (barring qualifying context), "crack around the door" would mean the cracks where the closed door doesn't fit tightly into the door frame; "crack of the door" would be (if precisely phrased, and again, barring qualifying context) "the partially open door".

Comment: It just depends on the context clues.